# In SAP B1 Hana Transactions Notifications, is it possible to exclude the Service Layer from its action?

Tags: hana, service-layer, sapb1

For SAP B1 HANA, I need to know the best way to exclude the Service Layer from the execution of a Transaction Notification or a TN PostNotification.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (:error != 0) THEN

    --- Exclude Service Layer --
    DECLARE notServiceLayer SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO notServiceLayer
    FROM "M_SESSION_CONTEXT"
    WHERE "M_SESSION_CONTEXT"."CONNECTION_ID" = CURRENT_CONNECTION
    AND "M_SESSION_CONTEXT"."KEY" = 'APPLICATION'
    AND "M_SESSION_CONTEXT"."VALUE" NOT LIKE '%ServiceLayer%';
    
    -- Errors are only shown when they're NOT requests from the SAP B1 Service Layer:
    IF notServiceLayer > 0 THEN
        SELECT :error, :error_message FROM "DUMMY";
    END IF;

END IF;
```